# Customer Object data display issue

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-attribute

I am trying to retrieve customer data with customer Object.

Below is the code:-

```
protected $customerRepository;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
) {
   $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
  }

public function getUser($userId) {
    $customerObj = $this->customerRepository->getById($userId);
    $customerEmail = $customerObj->getEmail();
    $customerAmount = $customerObj->getAmount();
}
```

I am getting below error when used above code:-

```
 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method 
 Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Data\\Customer::getAmount()
```

So I am using below code now to get amount value by thinking amount value is not set for that customer:-

```
 if(!isset($customerObj->getAmount())){
    $amount= '';
}else{      
    $amount= $customerObj->getAmount();
}
```

Now I am getting below error:-

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
```

How can I check the condition if that attribute value is not set, then I will set it as empty.

Is that can be checked? Please, anyone suggest me

Comment: share code of data provider class  `Vendor\Module\Model\Data\Customer` and

Comment: Yes, i have updated my question

Comment: i have asking to provide code of `Vendor\Module\Model\Data\Customer `

Comment: If you have  using repository then you must have data provider

Comment: Got it, you are right Amit, I was not defined that attribute in Model\Data\Customer file, now i am getting value as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code

```
$customerAmount=$customerObj->getCustomAttribute('bu_address1');
```

result will be

```
Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [attribute_code] => bu_address1
            [value] => Noida
        )

)
```

And for

```
$customerAmount=$customerObj->getCustomAttribute('bu_address1')->getValue();
```

Result will be

```
 Noida
```

Comment: I am getting below error after using your code Call to a member function getValue() on null, I am printing customer object, i can not see any value called amount, so i need to check that

Comment: may i know what class is for this object $this->customerRepository in your code ?

Comment: I am using \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface

Comment: you have done some thing wrong in attribute create see i have updated answer in post

Answer (score 1):

```
$customerAmount = $customer->getAttribute('amount') //or whatever the key is
$customerAmount = isset($customerAmount) ? $customerAmount : '';
```

Comment: same again, for me amount is not coming in object, so how can i check that condition? Above code didn't work for me

Comment: what do you mean "amount is not coming in object"? can you edit your question and show us how you created the attribute?

Comment: yes attribute is created properly but the value for that attribute is not set for particular customer, i need to check if that value exists, i need to show else i need to show as empty

Comment: how did you create it. how can you be sure it's created properly?